# Dynamically change model attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Is there a way to dynamically change attributes in a rails model?

Here is the scenario I currently have.  I have a client model with five clients inside.  Those clients have:

```
attr_accessible :name, :image, :order
```

The order attribute is so that the clients can be displayed in the order the admin would like them to be displayed.

So each of the five clients have an order of 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5.  Let's say then I create another client and would like that clients to have an order of 4.  If I do this the way I know how, the client orders will be 1, 2, 3, 4(new 4) ,4(old 4) ,5.

What I would like to have happen is that the last two clients have a 1 added to their order so the clients order will look like 1, 2, 3, 4(new 4) ,5(old 4) , 6(old 5).

This way it will be easier for me as the client list gets larger to just add the new clients where I want them to go in the order and have the rest of the clients' order dynamically change.

Answer (score 2):

In case you weren't already clear on how you might do this yourself, the following Rails code:

```
Client.all.update_all('sort_order = sort_order+1', ['sort_order >= ?', inserted_order])
```

would add one to the `sort_order` attribute of all client records whose order was greater than or equal to `inserted_order`.

Note: I changed the `order` attribute to `sort_order` to avoid conflict with the SQL keyword. Note sure why that wasn't an issue for you already.

Comment: What is inserted order here?  And is the >= ? also equal to inserted order?  And would this also effect the current client because in my example it is still >= 4.

Comment: It would represent the order you're trying to insert "at" (e.g. 4 in the OP's example).

Comment: Will this code impact both instance where order => 4?  Or just the old one?

Comment: Depends if you execute it before or after you save the record you inserting _at_ 4. :-)

Comment: When I run the command you gave me I get the error: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near "order": syntax error: UPDATE "studios" SET order = order+1 WHERE (order >= 2)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43291/discussion-between-user2184718-and-peter-alfvin)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the acts_as_list gem.

https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list

I haven't used it myself but I have known about it and I think it will do what you want.

Good luck!